# Excel display earlier of two dates

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet that displays the expiry date of Certificate 1 and Certificate 2. Candidates must have both dto be considered Certified. The Certification expiry date is the earlier of the two certificates so I use the following formula

```
=IF(Certificate 1 Expiry<Certificate 2 Expiry,Certificate 1 Expiry,Certificate 2 Expiry)
```

This works fine until somebody doesn't have an expiry date for one of the certificates and then the Certification Expiry Date is 01/01/1900.

How do I get the Certification Expiry Date to be blank if they are missing one of the certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`ISBLANK()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/isblank-function-dax-HA102838142.aspx) function and the [`MIN()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/min-HP005209176.aspx) function for a cleaner solution.

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(Certificate 1 Expiry),ISBLANK(Certificate 2 Expiry)),"",MIN(Certificate 1 Expiry,Certificate 2 Expiry))
```

**References**

[`IF()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx)

[`ISBLANK()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/isblank-function-dax-HA102838142.aspx)

[`MIN()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/min-HP005209176.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

best to use min rather than if and <

`=MIN(Certificate 1 Expiry,Certificate 2 Expiry)`

here is blank-if-either-is-blank

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(Certificate 1 Expiry),ISBLANK(Certificate 2 Expiry)),"",MIN(Certificate 1 Expiry,Certificate 2 Expiry))`
```

Comment: @Enilorac that is what you've asked for. the problem can be that one of the cells is not actually blank, but contains e.g. a space

Comment: The MIN formula works to give the closest date so thanks for the better formula but the second formula just gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

If none of the values can be text, you can multiply values to see if at least one is 0 (value of a blank cell is 0)

```
=IF(Cert1Exp * Cert2Exp, MIN(Cert1Exp, Cert2Exp), "")
```

you will get `#VALUE!` when the input is invalid (e.g. a space instead of blank cell), if you need custom error message, use:

```
=IFERROR(IF(Cert1Exp * Cert2Exp, MIN(Cert1Exp, Cert2Exp), ""), "Custom error")
```